# "Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel" while installing PyPy version of Numpy

Tags: software-installation, python

I am trying to install the PyPy distribution of Numpy (Note that PyPy requires a different version of Numpy than that found in the repositories), but get the error:

```
Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel
```

I do however have the latest python-dev installed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using software center?  Pypy is available in the repositories.

Comment: PyPy however requires a separate installation of Numpy. See [here](http://pypy.org/download.html)

Comment: I see that and they are describing the installation from the standpoint of you installing from their downloads.  Software center/apt-get will resolve dependencies so unless you require the version from the site it seems worth a shot to try software center, IMHO.

Comment: Yes but it does not work though. PyPy does not recognize the standard Numpy installation (I did try). I am more interested in why I am getting the error than in other ways of installing Numpy.

Comment: Are you using 14.04?  I wonder if it is because there are 2 versions of python installed.  I assumed you are doing the 2.7 versions.  Did you install the right python-dev version?

Comment: I am running 14.04 yes. I am not sure about the dev, I have the latest one, but am not sure which one I might need or how to install older ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somebody mentioned portable PyPy which I maintain. The stable builds indeed don't have numpy precompiled but I also build unstable builds from time to time which include numpy. You can see them here: https://bitbucket.org/squeaky/portable-pypy-weekly/downloads.

Comment: Excellent thank you @Squaky, I will check it out!

Answer (score 8):

The error is a bit misleading but the solution for me was to install [pypy-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/pypy-dev) (instead of `python-dev`).

Comment: I wanted to up-vote but found I already up-voted!!

Comment: Perfect answer. I am commenting to highlight importance of this answer for other coming here.

Answer (score 5):

I noted this on their site:

> Installing NumPy

NumPy is an exception to the rule that most packages work without changes. The “numpy” module needs to be installed from our own repository rather than from the official source.

If you have pip (the command-line assumes that it finds the pip belonging to PyPy, not the one from CPython):

```
pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy.git
```

Alternatively, the direct way:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy.git
cd numpy
pypy setup.py install
```

Note that NumPy support is still a work-in-progress, many things do not work and those that do may not be any faster than NumPy on CPython.

[Installing More Modules](http://pypy.org/download.html#installing-numpy)

Comment: I saw yes. I think I should try to install pip!

Comment: I wonder where this stands today, whether there's still a need, possibility or advantage to installing a _PyPy distribution of numpy_, if that's still a thing. Excuse my ignorance on PyPy parlance.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still facing this error in 2022, `pip3 install --upgrade pip` resolved the error for me.

Comment: Jesus, I would never have guessed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possibility.  I found this going through their webpage.  An alternate way to install (found off your link).  [portable binaries](https://github.com/squeaky-pl/portable-pypy)

When I mentioned versions, did you install python-dev or python3-dev?

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded it but have no Idea how to build it.

Comment: Directions on page say:  "The idea is that you just download an archive, uncompress it and run it instantly without installing any extra libraries or tweaking your OS. Currenly they are known to work across various DEB and RPM based distributions including RHEL/Centos 5 and later, Ubuntu and Debian stable."  Extract it in your home directory and you should find all you need then.

Comment: Extract, go into pypy folder that extracted, then into bin (using terminal) then type ./pypy and it runs :)  Option 2 use the full path to the pypy binary or if you added the resulting folder to your PATH you'd be able to type pypy.  I just had it running.

Comment: Seems to work! Except the Numpy issue is still an issue (-:

Comment: Hm, looking some more.  Did you note this on their site? "Note that NumPy support is still a work-in-progress, many things do not work and those that do may not be any faster than NumPy on CPython."

Comment: Yes I noted. I want to run a very basic program so don't think it will be a problem. But don't worry to much about it. You've already helped me more than anyone else on SE (-: I'm sure I will figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i use virtual environment with base python3.9 interpreter, but system default is python3.8. So when i tried to install 'sudo apt install python3-dev' it use 3.8 python3-dev, but my environment need 3.9.
Solution is change base python for virtual environment to system default 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to install python**3**-dev. If install `python-dev` it installed all for Python 2.7, which was the problem. So `sudo apt install python3-dev` should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question while installing torch or numpy.
the cmd was input was:
pip install torch
pip install numpy
the environment of my computer is python3.8, ubuntu 18.04, pip version is 23.0.1, however I get a note in terminal of ubuntu, then a new installing method was tried and it worked fine:
python -m pip install torch

Answer (score 0):

I did all of suggestions that other users in this question made. But after few days of wild goose chase, I removed my virtual environment. It seems that `opencv-python` has non compatible dependency to `torch` so you have to make your own build of opencv then install torch. This was solution in my case.